# disable messages.log and nioneo_logial.log.* in graph.db | Neo4j, Java

Tags: java, logging, neo4j

I am using **Neo4j** (edit: 2.1.2) from **Java** and `graph.db` folder grows huge (more than I can afford to store) while continuously writing data. I have reached more than 40 GB.

I've noticed that if I copy elsewhere the `graph.db` directory without `messages.log` and without all `nioneo_logial.log.*` files, the database is still consistent, I can still read it. Thus, I can rich affordable disk storage for the data (tens/hundreds of MB).

One solution is to regularly stop feeding the `graph.db`, delete all `*.log*` files and then restart the application. *This is not an acceptable solution!* :)

So, **is there any way of writing in `graph.db` without generating all these log files?**

**Note**:
I am writing to neo4j while into a transaction

```
final Transaction tx = db.beginTx();
```

where *db* is a *GraphDatabaseService* object.

Thank you,
Costin

Comment: What version of Neo4j are you using?

Comment: <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a config open `keep_logical_logs` which you can set to `false` to prevent the `nioneo_logical.log.*` files.

Providing a `custom-logback.xml` on your classpath with more rigid settings than the one shipping with the `.tar.gz` distributions can reduce the amount of lines written to `messages.log`.

Comment: Thank you Stefan. I will only discuss here the first point, I didn't try the second one yet. With `keep_logical_logs = "false"` I only get 3 `nioneo_logical.log.v*` files. With `keep_logical_logs = "0 files"` I get 2 *.log.v* files. Is there any way not to do anything at all?

Comment: *To do nothing* or *not to do*? What I want is `not to do` anything :)

Comment: Thank you, the second part worked. I've set the log level to error for messages.log.